JWTClaims causing server error 500 in my Xero callback function
Using the code in the PHP github documentation from XeroAPI I have a working callback function that receives user authentication details. We are working with multiple Xero connections so retrieving the connections and just selecting the first from that array will not work as it may not be the current connection being authorised. This cause issues with invoices from our US store being sent to our AU Xero account.
I have been trying to work with the JWTClaims to decode the access token so I can use the authentication_event_id to filter the connection results but it causes my callback to throw a 500 error with no other explanation. I have a basic try/catch but it isn't helping mitigate this and isn't showing any errors. When I use the access token manually in a test function, everything works perfectly and the expected results are returned. The moment I put it into my callback function, I get this 500 error.
Any ideas what may be causing it?
Here the portion that fails:
try {
    // Try to get an access token using the authorization code grant.
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        [
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
        ]
    );

    $token = (string) $accessToken->getToken();

    $claims = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\JWTClaims();
    $claims->decodeAccessToken($token);

    $auth_event_id = $claims->getAuthenticationEventId();

    $config = XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($token);
    $identityApi = new XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Api\IdentityApi(
        new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
        $config
    );

    $connection = $identityApi->getConnections();

    if(empty($connection)) {
        throw new Exception("connection not found");
    }

    // Save tokens, expiration, tenant_id, etc.
    $inputs  = array(
        'access_token' => $accessToken->getToken(),
        'expires' => $accessToken->getExpires(),
        'tenant_id' => $connection[0]->getTenantId(),
        'refresh_token' => $accessToken->getRefreshToken(),
        'id_token' => $accessToken->getValues()["id_token"],
        'account' => $account
    );

    // Handle saving the data here
} catch (XeroAPI\XeroPHP\ApiException $e) {
    echo "Callback failed: <br> " . $e;
    exit();
}

I have tried many different approaches. Removing $claims->decodeAccessToken($token); and $auth_event_id = $claims->getAuthenticationEventId(); fixes the error but not my problem. What am I missing here?? It seems so basic but it will not work for me. Thanks

If it's reproducible in your development environment - take xdebug and step through your code.
